# Do we use libstdc++.a and libstdc++.so at the same time when generating executable?

Tags: c++, linux, static, linker, libstdc++

If I choose to do:

```
gcc my.cpp -lstdc++
```

It links with libstdc++.so, right? But there're some c/c++ initialization part of code(global/static variables/objects, atexit() functions, etc), seems they should also require linking to libstdc++.a file.

So my question is, does the linking command always uses libstdc++.a for some reason, even if I specified to link with .so file?

Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you think that "some c/c++ initialization part of code ... should also require linking to libstdc++.a"?

Comment: Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293530/what-is-the-difference-between-so-and-a-files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `gcc my.cpp -lstdc++`

This is usually the wrong thing to do. Instead, you should do this:

```
g++ my.cpp
```

> It links with libstdc++.so, right?

Depends on how GCC was configured and installed, but most often yes.

> But there're some c/c++ initialization part of code(global/static variables/objects, atexit() functions, etc), seems they should also require linking to libstdc++.a file.

This is false. Where did you get this mistaken impression from?

> So my question is, does the linking command always uses libstdc++.a

No, not usually.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `g++ test.cpp` it links against "libstdc++" (defaults to the shared library if present, libstdc++.so) if you run `g++ -static-libstdc++ test.cpp` then it links against listdc++.a if possible.  Or `g++ -static`  which happens to imply -static-libstdc++